# .htaccess re-directs not working on a new server

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have copied a site that that sits under www.domain.co.uk onto a new, testing server which has the url http://c4034105.myzen.co.uk (ultimately we are going to point www.domain.co.uk at this new version)

I am finding that redirects don't appear to work. Here is part of the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php


#CONTACT
RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact/$ contact.php [L]
```

The first 404 redirect is working.

However, when the url http://c4034105.myzen.co.uk/memorials/contact is generated we want it to redirect to http://c4034105.myzen.co.uk/contact but it isn't. When it was under its domain.co.uk it worked fine.

What's wrong please

Thanks

Comment: its under public_html/.htaccess - same as where all the pages are

Answer (score 1):

the rules you posted only add the `.php` extension to http://www.example.com/contact, there's no rule which redirects http://example.com/memorials/contact to http://example.com/contact.
here's one:

```
RewriteRule ^memorials/contact/?$ /contact [L]
```

Comment: I added that rule you suggested and now it works - so thanks. What I don't understand is why it worked on the old site but not on the new one? - any ideas?

Comment: maybe you were using the rewriteBase directive to  provide a base for your rewrites (`RewriteBase /memorials/`)

Comment: Yes I couldn't see that in the .htaccess file. I wonder if it will just sort when domain moves

Comment: if you're placing your .htaccess at the root directory of your website, than I don't recommend using rewriteBase directive(it's more meant for sub directories htaccess). the rule I've posted in my answer should work with whatever domain.